# Can I express in HTML a character that doesn't have a Unicode value?

Tags: html, unicode, fonts, html-entities

Is it possible to express in HTML a character that doesn't have a Unicode value?

It would be fine as HEX, HTML Code or Entity, or anything a browser can read.

I good example of this would be expressing OpenType features without using CSS. In the font the target character would be exported as `y.ss01` but isn't assigned a Unicode value.

Comment: Unfortunately HTML can't access [glyphs via index](https://typedrawers.com/discussion/3123/displaying-non-unicode-character-on-website). You could auto generate unicode in a font editor like fontlab and save a special version of your font for web display. Otherwise you might use a library like opentype.js if you ultimate goal is to show all available features and glyphs